# Proof of linear independency

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $\mathbf{u}_{1},\mathbf{u}_{2},\ldots,\mathbf{u}_{k}$ be linearly independent vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Let $\mathbf{A}$ be an $m\times n$ matrix and $V$ the solution space of the homogeneous linear system $\mathbf{A}x=\mathbf{0}$.

Prove that if $V\cap\text{span}\{\mathbf{u}_{1},\mathbf{u}_{2},\ldots,\mathbf{u}_{k}\}=\{\mathbf{0}\}$, then $\mathbf{A}\mathbf{u}_{1},\mathbf{A}\mathbf{u}_{2},\ldots,\mathbf{A}\mathbf{u}_{k}$ are linearly independent.

I understand that the solution space of $\mathbf{A}x=\mathbf{0}$ is just the nullspace of $\mathbf{A}$, but how can I proceed from here? I have no idea how to utilise the intersection condition. Any kind soul please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that for $\;c_1,...,c_k\in\Bbb R\;$ we have (we use here linearity of matrices)

$$0=\sum_{i=1}^k c_iAu_i=\sum_{i=1}^kA(c_iu_i)=A\left(\sum_{i=1}^k c_iu_i\right)\implies$$

$$\implies \sum_{i=1}^k c_iu_i\in V\implies\sum_{i=1}^k c_iu_i=0 \;\text{(since we're given}\;V\cap\text{Span}\,\{u_1,...,u_k\}=0)\implies$$

$$\implies c_i=0\;\;\forall\,i=1,2...,k\;\;\text{(why?)}\implies\;\;Q.E.D.$$